# Multiple pull chain light fixtures discovered to not be working

Tags: electrical

I have four pull chain fixtures for light bulbs that do not work. I have other pull chain fixures that do work. I checked the light bulbs and circuit breakers and they are fine. Three of the pull chain fixtures were add on's on our second floor and installed after we bought this house about 15 years ago. I assume these three are connected in some manner and suspicious that something went wrong based on the installation. However, that may not explain the fourth fixture that does not work that is in our basement. Any troubleshooting or other suggestions are appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are they on the same breaker, or different breakers?

Comment: Just because they have a pull chain, doesn't mean that's the only place they're switched.  You probably have a light switch somewhere, perhaps somewhere not obvious, that works those lights.   If you had the lights switched off at the pull chain, then the switch would appear to do nothing.